# issues with xrange and list iteration

Tags: python, iterator

I'm trying to iterate over a list created by spliting the response string in the requests module my goal is to manipulate and add the captured data to a set; each page in the xrange should have exactly 40 of the value that I'm looking for but seemingly my code is taking the last value of each iteration and adding that to the list rather than each value. Consequently the loop that should perform some string addition like so: `'http://example.com' + link1 + '.html', 'http://example.com' + link2 + '.html', 'http://example.com' + link3 + '.html', ...` instead returns unwanted substrings like so: `'http://example.com' + 'l' + '.html', 'http://example.com' + 'i' + '.html', 'http://example.com' + 'n' + '.html' , ...`. How can I change this to accomplish the goal and why did it happen.

```
last_pg = 10
    BASE_URL = 'http://example.com?act=view&NowPage=%s'
    urls = set()
    for i in xrange(last_pg):
        response = requests.get(BASE_URL % i)
        parsed_body = html.fromstring(response.text)
        links = response.text.split('-p-')[-1].split('-cat-')[0]
        print links #this seems to print the last value of each iteration rather than all of them
        for link in links:# this loop breaks down each link value into substrings and performs the interpolation on the substrings
            finallink = ('http://example.com-' + link.encode('ascii', 'ignore') + '.html')
            urls.add(finallink)
            print "added %s to que" % finallink
    print urls
    print len(urls)
```

Comment: Can you add more detail about what an example of `response.text` would be? When you do `.split()[-1]` that only gets the last element of the split, and same with the second split. You want to keep the list of splits and iterate through those, not just a single split element. The reason you are just getting single letters is because you are iterating through a string and not a list of strings, so it is yielding the characters from the string, instead of individual strings.

Comment: Response.text in this case comes from the requests library and is just the full text string of a web page I would like to parse. This web page actually returns json to the browser but it has the strings that I'm looking for so I thought I could split that string by the unique identifiers that come before and after each url that I would like to parse out. I'm not sure why that split isn't returning a list am I not allowed to chain the splits like so: response.text.split('-p-')[-1].split('-cat-')[0]

Comment: The split is returning a list, but you are using an index of that list to do the second split so you are only getting a single element from it. `response.text.split()` gives you a list, but `response.text.split()[-1]` gives you the last element of that list. If you did something like `links = [x.split('-cat-')[0] for x in response.split('-p-')]` you could maybe get a list of what you wanted, but you might have to break it up even further. Its hard to say exactly what you're trying to parse without an example of the actual string contents of `response.text`.

Comment: Ok I think I understand what's going on; I come from ruby and that type of chained notation would work. Thanks for the info I will make a few edits and give you the check if this resolves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split is returning a list, but you are using an index of that list to do the second split so you are only getting a single element from it. `response.text.split('-p-')` gives you a list, but `response.text.split('-p-')[-1]` gives you the last element of that list. If you did something like:

```
links = [x.split('-cat-')[0] for x in response.split('-p-')]
```

you could maybe get a list of what you wanted, but you might have to do some more processing either by changing the index you get from the `'-cat-'` split or by doing another iteration through the list from that split.

The reason you are just getting single letters is because you are iterating through a string and not a list of strings, so it is yielding the characters from the string, instead of individual strings.

Comment: This worked perfectly, as a related aside; how come .pop doesn't work as expected; I tried to delete the first (0) index of the results of the links list because it had some erroneous data but links.pop(0) didn't work; I eventually had to result to using final_links = links[1:]. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @jcuwaz `.pop(0)` will return the first element not the modified list, so I'm guessing that was your problem. You would probably just want to do `links.pop(0)` instead of `final_links = links.pop(0)` if that was your issue.